# Awesome WM weather widget issue

Tags: linux, arch-linux, awesome-wm, widgets

I am using Awesome WM as window manager,
to get more flexible environment. But when I was doing a weather widget,
using 'vicious' library, I could made some mistake...
The problem is the next: any time I want to get on-desktop weather info, I get a vector of `N/A`'s. I cannot recognize, where the actually problem is... While getting info from vicious source, everything is recieved. Maybe it is a bug of vicious widget?
Screenshots(just look at up left corner of the screen):
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2WfM.jpg).
Widget code:

```
-- {{{ Weather widget
weatherBox = wibox({ type = "desktop", visible = true, bg = "#00000000" })
weatherBox:geometry({ x = 10, y = 25, width = 300, height = 85 })
weatherLayout = wibox.layout.fixed.horizontal()

weatherWidget = boxWidget(vicious.widgets.weather,
    function(w, data)
        local city        = data["{city}"]
        local wind_speed  = data["{windkmh}"]
        local wind        = data["{wind}"]
        local sky         = data["{sky}"]
        local humidity    = data["{humid}"]
        local temperature = data["{tempc}"]

        return 'Location: ' .. city .. '\n' ..
               'Wind: ' .. wind_speed .. ', ' .. wind_speed .. '\n' ..
               'Sky: ' .. sky .. '\n' ..
               'Humidity: ' .. humidity .. '\n' ..
               'Temerature: ' .. temperature .. ', C\n'
    end, 1, "UUEE")

weatherLayout:add(weatherWidget)
weatherBox:set_widget(weatherLayout)
-- }}}
```

---

Comment: Where is `data` being passed in from? I also possibly see another small problem, you're using `wind_speed` twice when displaying your wind output. I assume you want something more like wind_speed and wind(direction).

Comment: @DrZoo I use vicious library to get some basic interfaces. The actual code of widget is [here](https://github.com/Mic92/vicious/blob/master/widgets/weather_all.lua).

Comment: @DrZoo Vicious library is used to get some interfaces. The code of widget worker is here(https://github.com/Mic92/vicious/blob/master/widgets/weather_all.lua).

Comment: This may be better put on StackOverflow. But it seems like you're hitting the initialization setting each variable to "N/A".  On line 46 of `weather_all.lua` you're hitting `if ws == nil then return _weather end`, which is returning the default initialization of each element, rather than continuing on to line 51. I would try to figure out what is happening on line 44 and 45 with the writing to a file and reading from it.

Comment: @DrZoo OK, I will try re-writing widget code to my own and I hope it will be working...